# How to get all Users and echo if they work or not?

Tags: grep, echo

How do I get a list of users(given from the command line) with `grep` and output if they are logged/work or not ?

Comment: `w` from the _procps_ package lists the currently logged in users. See if it helps you. (Not sure what you actually want to find out.)

Comment: It is a homework assignment and doesn't have a real applicability.

Comment: @manatwork, `procps` is a bundle of a few process related utilities for Linux, `w` is a non-standard command originated in `BSD`. The OP didn't mention what OS he was using, it could be all and/or any as far as we can tell. `who` is a standard Unix command (XSI extension in POSIX).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 perl -le 'print while $_=getpwent' | sort
```

Will give you the list of user names.

```
 ps -eo user= | sort -u
```

Will give you a list of user names whose corresponding uids are the effective user ids of at least one process running.

```
 who | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u
```

Will list the users currently *logged in*

```
 printf '%s\n' "$@" | sort -u
```

Will list the users passed as argument to your script.

Now that you have those 4 lists, you can use the `comm` command to select which of those are common to any two given lists or appear in one but not the other.

With a shell supporting process substitution, you can also do without creating temp files.

For instance:

```
#! /bin/bash -
comm -12 <(printf '%s\n' "$@" | sort -u) \
         <(ps -eo user= | sort -u)
```

Called as:

```
./my-script root mythul stephane
```

will report which of those 3 users have running processes (assuming there's a one-to-one relationship between username and uid on your system).